# Проверка домена через DNS Google

Tags: c++, dns, google-public-dns

Реализована вот такая простая проверка на подмену ip, но это можно обойти. Как можно сделать такую проверку через Google DNS?

```
WSADATA wsaData = { 0, };
struct in_addr addr = { 0, };
struct hostent * res;
int i = 0;

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

res = gethostbyname("site.ru");
while (res->h_addr_list[i] != 0)
{
    addr.s_addr = *(u_long *)res->h_addr_list[i++];
}

string ip = (inet_ntoa(addr));

if ("127.0.0.1" == ip)
{
    printf("all ok");
}
else
{
    printf("not same");
}

system("pause >> null");
```

Comment: Можно вызвать nslookup с нужными параметрами и прочитать его вывод

Comment: Кстати, DNS может вернуть больше одного IP, вам нужно и такие случаи корректно обрабатывать

Comment: Кстати, запросы в любой dns то же можно обойти, перехватив 53 порт на свою dns и вы даже не сможете понять, что вам ответил не google...

Comment: Наверное, можно еще настроить маршрутизацию, чтобы запросы к Гуглу на самом деле шли на другой сервер... :-)